# wlan0: deauthenticated (Reason: 15)

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless

I can't connect to a specific wifi network `freebox_CYFQRO`. The network appears in the list of available networks, but the system can't authenticate.

I can connect to this network `freebox_CYFQRO` with the same hardware on Windows. I can connect to my mobile phone access point `AndroidAP` from the same PC on Ubuntu.

Here is the loop if face :

```
[  927.225632] wlan0: authenticate with MAC 'freebox_CYFQRO' [AN12] (try 1)
[  927.227578] wlan0: authenticated
[  927.228147] wlan0: associate with MAC 'freebox_CYFQRO' [AN12] (try 1)
[  927.237311] wlan0: RX AssocResp from MAC 'freebox_CYFQRO' [AN12] (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[  927.237316] wlan0: associated
[  934.174350] wlan0: deauthenticated from MAC 'freebox_CYFQRO' [AN12] (Reason: 15)
```

Here is the [full log file / specs](http://pastebin.com/L5z6cC9X).

Comment: Set your country code in `/etc/default/crda` and reboot, and delete your network profile for freebox_CYFQRD, and try to connect again. It'll ask for your network password this time.

Comment: Sorry @heynnema, it didn't work. I've also added `COUNTRY=FR` to the file `/etc/environment`. I have to say this connection was working a few week ago.

Comment: Did you **delete** the connection profile? Are you using WPA2-AES?

Comment: I think so, using the gui network manager. I think I'm using WPA-Personal, according a Windows 10 PC.

Comment: But... **did you delete your connection profile for freebox_CYFQRO?** It's MTU looks wrong. We can't fix this problem if you don't do my recommendations. And you should set your router to WPA2-AES.

Comment: Yes, I've done that using the gui. I cannot improvre the router encryption level, it is old.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas then.

Comment: I've changed the wifi canal and rebooted the router. It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the wifi channel and rebooted the router. It works fine.